# Can you explain in different sentences what is meant in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> "I wanted to tell you, little mouse, that my cousin had a little son, white with Brown spots, and she wants to me to be godmother to that little kitten. Let me go out today, and do you take care of the house Alone." " Yes go certanly," replied the mouse, "and when you eat anything Good , think of me: **i should very much Like a drop of the red christening wine "**

What is the difference between i Like and i should Like in this sentence. This story is *the Cat and the mouse in partnership* in my story book

Comment: What is the problem here?  Is it the "I should..." phrase.  Or "a drop of" or "red christening wine"  If you don't tell us why the question is hard for you we don't know what we need to explain.

Comment: Can you explain to me why you can't capitalize the I  pronoun?? All that trouble to reproduce the entire paragraph and then not write I. Also, you have a typo. :)

Comment: Make sure you copy the text exactly.  There are at least two typos: It should be " I should" (not "i should" and "like" (not Like).

Comment: Finally, you need to tell us the source of the quote.  You can say "this was written by ... in the book called ....."  Or you can insert a URL to link to the source.

Comment: What is the difference between i Like and i should Like in this sentence. This story is the Cat and the mouse in partnership in my story book.

Comment: Why are you using capital letters for some words, but not for 'I'? It should be written _I like_ and _I should like_.

Comment: My phone does it so. I am too lazy to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rather old translation, and the English is rather dated, and perhaps influenced by the German original (This is a tale collected in German by the Brothers Grimm).

It is common to use "I would like" as a polite way of saying "I want".

In older styles of English "Should" is used with "I" instead of "would".

> I should like a slice of cake / He would like a slice of cake.

So the mouse is saying "I want a little of the red wine".

There is no need to copy this when you ask for something in modern English.

Answer (score 2):

> I should very much like a drop of the red christening wine

"I should like" is a conditional statement that sounds rather outdated these days, with a meaning similar to "I would like." See [this English.SA question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/19438/421933) for more details.

"I should *very much* like" adds an intensifying phrase modifying the verb "like."

"A drop" is figuratively used to mean "a small amount of liquid" but when the speaker is a mouse might be taken more literally than usual.

"Red wine" is a type of wine. To be more specific, the mouse is talking about "christening wine" which is the wine used in a christening ceremony, as for [a baby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baptism) or [a ship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceremonial_ship_launching).

So the sentence means:

> I would strongly enjoy having a little bit of the red wine used in a baptism ceremony.

Comment: ... except that "the red wine used in a baptism ceremony" does not quite do the job. The mouse is referring to a specific bottle of red christening wine that has already been referred to. The way you put it, he is merely asking for a drop of any of the variety of red wine which is used for christening.

Comment: @PrimeMover I don't have the book, so I didn't know the wine had been discussed already.

Comment: Nor have I. It's obvious from the way the original sentence is structured. "... the red christening wine". If he meant any random instance of red christening wine, it would have said "some red christening wine".